# Bootstrap Datetimepicker function moment() issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker with Rails 4.
Issues is with, when I have validations on the datetimepicker.

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A',
  minDate: moment(),
  widgetPositioning: {
         horizontal: 'auto',
         vertical: 'auto'
     }
});
```

So, with this I cannot select the datetime before current time which is my requirement. But when I edit the particular record, I get the current time only. It does not shows me the saved datetime from the datatbase.
If I remove the minDate, it shows me the correct datetime.

Is there any way to handle this ? Or I have to handle through backend only by removing the minDate?

This is the link which I am following:
 https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm A',
  minDate: moment(),
  keepInvalid: $('#start_date').val() ? true : false,
  widgetPositioning: {
    horizontal: 'auto',
    vertical: 'auto'
  }
});
```

Comment: This is working for the first time(while new record creation). If I have any errors in the page after submit, then minDate doesn't work. It takes as false. & we can select previous dates also. While on editing the record, it always has values, so false for minDate.

Comment: @Avinash if only the calendar selection is what's important to you and not the date automatically overriding stuff, then the code I just changed might work for you.

Comment: its showing the saved date with this. But at the same time it is allowing me to select past dates as well. Is there any way to hide the past dates once we click on the picker?